# How do I extract values from pulp model

Tags: python, pulp

````
```
print("Total Cost:", model.objective.value())
# Decision Variables
for v in model.variables():
    try:
        print(v.name,"=", v.value())
    except:
        print("error couldnt find value")
```

Total Cost: 1239859526.0
X_Apple = 833167.0
X_Huawei = 100.0
X_Oppo = 100.0
X_Samsung = 35.0
````

How do I extract the values separately from this pulp solution?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with extract the values seperately from the pulp solution ? do you want the data as a CSV file ?

Answer (score 0):

`print(dir(prob))` prints a list of attributes for `prob`

`variables` and `variablesDict` are among them:

```
prob.variables()[0].name
prob.variables()[0].value()

prob.variablesDict()['X_Apple'].name
prob.variablesDict()['X_Apple'].value()
```